# Can this set of equations be solved explicitly for algebraic curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, computational-geometry

In my recent work I stumbled upon a set of two equations. I'm interested in solving by eliminating auxiliary variable "$z$" and getting algebraic curve in terms of $x$ and $y$ given by the zero locus of some polynomial.

$$  \begin{cases} y = e^{x \partial_x W (x,z) }= \frac{(-1)^{C_{11}}x^{C_{11}} z^{1 - C_{11} + C_{12}}}{z-x} \\ 1 = e^{z \partial_z W(x,z)} = \frac{(-1)^{C_{22}-C_{11}}x^{C_{12}-C_{11}}(x-z) z^{C_{11} - 1 - 2 C_{12} + C_{22}}}{z-1} \end{cases} $$

or in polynomial form:
$$ \begin{cases} P(y,x,z) = z^{C_{12}+1} x^{C_{11}} (-1)^{C_{11}} - y z^{C_{11}+1} + y x z^{C_{11}} = 0 \\ Q(y,x,z) = z^{C_{12}+2} -  z^{C_{12}+1} + (-1)^{1 - C_{11} + C_{22}} x^{C_{12}-C_{11}} (x-z)  z^{C_{22}+ C_{11} +1}=0 \end{cases} $$

$C_{ij}$ are assumed to be positive (or zero) integer coefficients. Moreover, one of them can be set to zero. There is additionally a symmetry that exchanges $C_{11} \leftrightarrow C_{22}$ which gives the same algebraic curve.

Note that these equations can be solved by calculating the determinant of the Sylvester matrix of $P$ and $Q$ or the polynomial resultant if we set the coefficients $C_{ij}$ to some value. Also note that algebraic curves can be easily found by taking power of $z$ to be linear in the set of equations. One of possible solutions is for $C_{12}=C_{22}$: $$ A(x,y) = (-1)^{C_{11}} x^{C_{11}} ((-1)^{C_{12}+1} x^{C_{12}}+y)^{1 - C_{11} + C_{12}} + y^{1 - C_{11} + C_{12}} ( (-1)^{C_{12}} x^{C_{12}} + (x-1)y)$$

My questions are:
Can this set of equations be solved explicitly for arbitrary (positive integer and zero) $C_{ij}$ ? That is, can we eliminate $z$ to get some algebraic curve or family of algebraic curves dependent on parameters $C_{ij}$ in variables $x$ and $y$?

If not, is there a reason why?

Are Groebner bases techniques advanced enough to deal with such a problem?

Comment: What is the role of $W(x,z)$ in the 1st set of equations? Also, the 2nd equation there does not involve $y$---how do you use it?

Comment: $W(x,z)$ is just some function of $x$ and $z$ that gives this set of equations. You use the second equation to eliminate $z$,it can be rewritten as $\partial_z W(x,z) = 0 $, but the form I've given is more convenient. $y$ is involved only in the first equation, you can say that the first equation defines $y$, you cannot get it otherwise.

Comment: If there is a universal (working for arbitrary $C_{ij}$) equation for the curve then you might be able to find it by expanding the resultant of $P$ and $Q$ for several values of these parameters.